# How to create geometric pie shapes in OpenLayers 7.3.x

Tags: openlayers

I am trying to create a pie slice shape using the following bit of code.  However something is off as the start position of the shape is not what I expect it to be. I would like to use North as 0 degrees and not East as 0 degrees (East is the default in OpenLayers).  Example Code is shown below:

```
// Define a lat/long starting point
const someCenterLonLatValue = ...;

// Create a circle
Circle circle = new Circle(someCenterLonLatValue, someRadiusInMeters);

// Define a starting degree and subtract 90 degrees from it 
// since I want North to be 0 degrees
const startAtDegree = 22.5 - 90;

// Define how many degrees wide it should be
const howManyDegreesWide = 33;

// Create a polygon that has 360 points starting at the degree I want
const poly = fromCircle(circle, 360, startAtDegree);

// Grab the coordinates from the polygon
const coords = poly.getCoordinates(false)[0];

// Create the pie slice shape
const pieShape = coords.slice(0, howManyDegreesWide);

// Close the shape
pieShape.push(...[someCenterLonLatValue, pieShape[0]]);

// Overwrite the polygon with the pie shape
poly.setCoordinates([pieShape]);

// Test cases: Sorry I don't have pictures but this is the best
// I can do

// Test 1: startAtDegree=22.5 and howManyDegreesWide=45. 
// Result: Shape looks correct but starts a couple degrees before 0

// Test 2: startAtDegree=0 and howManyDegreesWide=90. 
// Result: Shape looks correct but fills in the area 
// between 210/300 degrees

// Test 3: startAtDegree=0 and howManyDegreesWide=270. 
// Result: Shape looks correct but does NOT fill in the area
// between 120/210 degrees

// Test 4: startAtDegree=90 and howManyDegreesWide=270. 
// Result: Shape looks correct but fills in the area between 
// 90 and 360 degrees. So this one is correct!

// Test 5: startAtDegree=7 and howManyDegreesWide=25. 
// Result: Shape looks correct but fills in the area between 
// roughly 165 and 190 degrees.
```

Comment: From your question is not clear what is your problem: you don't like the input parameters for the correct final result, or you can't get correct result at all? A picture or two would help.

Comment: Using my input parameters gives me incorrect output parameters. Unfortunately I cannot provide a picture

Comment: I have added a couple test cases to the bottom of the original post. Thanks!

Comment: See the documentation https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_geom_Polygon.html#.fromCircle
"Start angle for the first vertex of the polygon in counter-clockwise **radians**. 0 means East. Default is 0."  To move the start from east to north you will need `const startAtRadians = Math.PI / 2;`

Comment: Mike - Yep, that was my stumbling block, thanks!  If you want to answer the question in a post I can award you the checkmark!